# Rule for Summing a Finite Geometric Series.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-series

What is the rule?

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}6^i
$$

and

$$
\sum_{i=5}^{N}6^i
$$

Mostly interested in #1 and the summation rules for c^x. But if you feel like doing my HW go ahead :)

Comment: See the wiki article on geometric series [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: Seeing that the article and others use n-1 for geometric series and mine uses n, and that is the one part of summations that I am hazy on, can you confirm that the answer for the first example is (1-6^n)/(1-6)? Or is it 6^n+1

Comment: If the upper summation index is $n-1$, it's $(1-6^{n})/(1-6)$. If the upper summation index is $n$, everything shifts and the result is $(1-6^{n+1})/(1-6)$.

Comment: That was my own instinct! Wish I could mark you answered :)

Comment: It's all good, glad it makes sense for you now.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles uses $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$ instead of $\sum_{i=1}^n.$ But the idea is the same. Might want to try your answer with $N=5$ as in my Answer. That way you can use a calculator to compare numerical results.

Comment: I am looking at your answer but I am confused. It looks like you are responding to #1, but setting n-1 to 5? Or are you answering the second one? It is supposed to be n, i=5

Comment: In my Answ with $N=5$ terms in #1, one has $6 +   36+  216+ 1296+ 7776 = 9330,$ Also, $\frac{6-6^6}{-5} = 9330.$

Comment: It is N=n and i=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to summing geometric series that I have seen:

$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^5 r^i = r + r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + r^5.$$
$$ rS = r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + r^5 + r^6.$$
$$ S - rS = S(1-r) = r - r^6.$$

So

$$ S = \frac{r - r^6}{1 - r}.$$

*Notes:* (a) I used the same notation as the Wikipedia article linked above,
in case you want to look at both. (b) If $r = 1/2,$ something similar can be used to find $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1/2)^i = 1.$

Comment: Voted. Can you provide insight into the differences between n, n-1 and i=0, i=1, and i=m? Obviously series and sum are different but what about these values -- It was not clear why you chose the first solution, i=0, instead of the second solution, i=m, as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Exponential_terms

Answer (score 3):

This is a famous use of telescoping series. We can write down the general case as:

$$S_N=\sum_{n=n_0}^Nr^n$$

Or, alternatively:

$$S_N=r^{n_0}+r^{n_0+1}+...+r^{N-1}+r^N$$

The "trick" is to multiply both sides by $(1-r)$. Many of the terms on the left will cancel, and you should be able to obtain a simple expression for $S_N$.

Comment: I didn't mark you answered but your answer was appreciated. Voted.

Comment: I started working on my answer before yours appeared. Nice general approach (+1).